# Popup contact form Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I dose a contact form with contact form 7 , but I need to show it when i press on button on front end like a popup , how can I make it ,
don't use any plugins , I want to know how to code it

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to do that. If you are keen on learning that, as you describe, then follow some online tutorials like w3schools.com

Comment: yea the JS helped me yesterday :D , thank you for your attention I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a lightbox and hide the display style
Create a button that display this lightbox by clicking on it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-popup").click(function(){
    $(".lightbox").slideDown();
  });
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".lightbox").slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center
}
h1{
  margin-top: 50px
}
.content{
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 50px
}
.lightbox{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #999;
   opicity: 0.8;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 99999;
}
.popup{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left:  0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup-content{
  background: #fff;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.close{
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    color:  #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html >
<head>
<title>PopUp</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>my title</h1>
<div class="content">my content</div>
<button class="show-popup">Show PopUp</button>
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup-content">
          PopUp content
          <span class="close">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yea the JS helped me yesterday :D , thank you for your attention I appreciate that :)